# Within a multiline string how does one match sequences of new lines where each line starts with the pipe character

Tags: javascript, regex, split, match, multiline

Hey I have a string that is kind of like this:

String:

```
foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar
bar
```

And I need a regular expression that matches everything from the first "|" at a line start to the first line that doesn't start with a "|" (as one match).
So the match in the shown example would be like this:

Correct Match:

```
[
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
,
|bar foo
|foo bar
]
```

I came up with this `/\|([\s\S]+)(\n\|)/g` but that matches the following and that incorrect:

Incorrect Match:

```
[
| bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|
]
```

I hope you can understand what I need and thank you for your time!

Comment: So you want it to stop the first time it encounters a line that doesn't start with `|`. Can you clarify whether or not you want to include this line? In the example you gave for the correct matches, one match includes the ending line and one does not.

Comment: [`... .split(/^[^|].*\n/gm).filter(str => str !== '');`](https://regex101.com/r/IeiZyj/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

In accordance with your question, to match everything from the first "|" at a line start to the first line that doesn't start with a "|", you can use this regex:

```regex
/^\|([\s\S]*?)(?:(?!^[^\|])[\s\S])*/gm
```

Its important to note that the `m` flag (multiline) is required in order to match multiline strings.

Given you example string of

```
foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar
bar
```

this will match

```
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
```

and

```
|bar foo
|foo bar
```

### How it works:

The `^\|` matches any line that starts with a "|" character. Then, the `([\s\S]*?)` matches 0 or more of any character including new lines "Lazily" (meaning only capturing the minimum). Finally the `(?:(?!^[^\|])[\s\S])*` matches up until a new line (`^`) that does not begin with a "|" (`[^\|]`).

Here is a link to [Regexr](https://regexr.com/65frq) that shows more about how it works and an example of it in action.

```js
const str =
`foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar
bar`

console.log(str.match(/^\|([\s\S]*?)(?:(?!^[^\|])[\s\S])*/gm))
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger I tested it and it worked on the provided test cases. The `m` (multiline) flag is required to parse multiline strings as noted in my answer. There is also a link to see it in action.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Ah I now see what you mean. It's because I used `.` instead of `[\s\S]`. I will edit my answer. Also I think my answer is way more concise sine it doesn't rely on any javascript, just pure Regex.

Comment: nice. Thanks for the fix. And the executable snippet. The last one btw, together with some edge case tests always ensures/proves a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

An approach just based on [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) might not in any case work for the OP's requirement(s). But a working solution definitely can be achieved with both a regex based [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and a sanitizing [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ... something similar to ...

```
`multilines`.split(/(?:^[^|].*\n)+/gm).filter(str => str !== '' && str !== '\n');
```

**Why is that?**

Since the OP wants to preserve any substring which features consecutive new lines, each starting with `|`, the OP simply needs to split the multiline string at each new line which does not start with `|`.

Thus a 1st working regex might be [`/^[^|].*\n/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/IeiZyj/1). It reads like that ...

- `/ ... /m` operate within `m`ulti-line mode thus enabling `^` to match each new line within a string.
- `^[^|]` at the beginning of each new line match a character which is not a pipe/`|` ... then ...
- `.*\n` match anything else including the last line break

This match will be used for a [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) operation, thus separating the lines the OP is looking for from the ones which should be excluded from the OP's desired result.

Due to the not yet that ideal regex and due to the nature of `split` the result features some artifacts ...

```js
console.log(
`foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar
bar`.split(/^[^|].*\n/gm)
);

console.log(
`foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar
bar

foo | bar
bar

|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar

bar

`.split(/^[^|].*\n/gm)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... which we get rid of within the next code iteration.

```js
console.log(
`foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar
bar`.split(/(?:^[^|].*\n)+/gm)
);

console.log(
`foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar

bar

foo | bar
bar

|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar

bar

`.split(/(?:^[^|].*\n)+/gm)
);

console.log(
`foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar
bar`.split(/(?:^[^|].*\n)+/gm).filter(str => str !== '' && str !== '\n')
);

console.log(
`foo | bar
|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar

bar

foo | bar
bar

|foo | bar
|foo bar
|bar foo foo
foo bar
|bar foo
|foo bar

bar

`.split(/(?:^[^|].*\n)+/gm).filter(str => str !== '' && str !== '\n')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The 1st regex ... `/^[^|].*\n/gm` ... got improved to [`/(?:^[^|].*\n)+/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/IeiZyj/2). Thus the 2nd version now matches sequences of unwanted new-lines (without capturing them ... `(?: ...)`).

The result almost covers the OP's requirements. But for edge cases one still can encounter artifacts within the result array. Thus, in order to always be on the save side, one needs to sanitize the latter via a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) condition.